# Jquery Datatable - Passing value from one "Data" element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using the JQuery datatable. 
I have made the first column of the table, which is RequestNo, as clickable.

Consider the following script :

```
  "ajax":
     {
         "url": "/Request/Search/LoadData",
         "type": "POST",
         "datatype": "json",
         "data": function (d) {
             d.obj = searchFilters();
         },
      },

     "columns":
     [
             {
                 "data": "RequestNo",
                 "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                      //if Status=="Draft"
                     {return '<a href="/Request/Request?RequestId=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';}
                  else{//return to some another another link}
                 }
             },
             { "data": "Status" }  // this value is the deciding factor
```

What I want to do is:
-If the value returned for Status is "Draft" then, if the RequestNo field is clicked in the UI, it should return to the URL mentioned in the above IF Block..
-Else if the value is other than "Draft" then it should return to another URL

What I'm unable to do is to pass the value of Status to the above specified function in "render"

Can anyone tell me how can I pass the value of Status to the function in the "render" of RequestNo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `row` to function and get value for `status`

```
"render": function (data, type, row,full, meta) {
           if(row.Status=="Draft")
           {
             return '<a href="/Request/Request?RequestId=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
           }
           else{
             //return to some another another link}
               }
```

Also i think you need `row.RequestNo` instead of `data` here `?RequestId=' + data + '"`

Comment: No @Leopard the link I provided in href will do just fine because it's the RequestNo it needs to fetch. Hence adding 'data' is sufficient. It'll appropriately take the current row value.

Comment: And thanks a ton for your reply @Leopard. Passing 'row' to function worked. Thanks again